# Jenkins: prevent Deploy from running with Selenium Tests

Tags: deployment, selenium, jenkins, hudson, selenium-webdriver

we have about 20 selenium builds and 1 deployment build (for every of 4 environments)
what is the best way to prevent deployments and selenium tests from running simultaneously?

to use ThrottleConcurrentBuilds plugin i'll need to create 20 categories of 2 builds in each - Deployment+SeleniumJob1, Deployment+SeleniumJob2, Deployment+SeleniumJob3 etc.

and when I'll do it for every environment, i'll get 80 categories in total

is there any better way to do it?

Comment: why you can't use on post-build action - Build Other Project?
Deployment->SeleniumJob1->SeleniumJob2->... etc
21*4=84 projects.

Comment: because I have 8 selenium slaves and over 600 tests, which run during the day simultaneously and sometimes they get in conflicts with Deoployment. yes we have scheduled nightly builds but we're running jobs during the day as well